# wcf message size causing permission issue

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0, iis-6

silverlight 3.0 client

wcf 3.0 VS.Net 2005 Web Site Win 2003 Server

50 column observable collection.

return observable collection  select top 975 * ... no problem

return observable collection  select * .... Issue

On SL client after proxy.Get 50 col OC

logon screen from win 2003 server pops up

Mever makes it to the completed event.

Comment: maybe you could rewrite the question for humans?

Comment: possible duplicate of [configure console app to receive more than 65536 from wcf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844823/configure-console-app-to-receive-more-than-65536-from-wcf)

Answer (score 0):

You can check maxstringcontentlength, maxbuffersize, and maxreceivedmessagesize in config file.