# configure console app to receive more than 65536 from wcf

Tags: wcf, console, c#-2.0

Error Message:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

svc.map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceReference>
    <ProxyGenerationParameters
        ServiceReferenceUri="http://d3w9501/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc"
        Name="svc"
        NotifyPropertyChange="False"
        UseObservableCollection="False">
    </ProxyGenerationParameters>
    <EndPoints>
        <EndPoint
            Address="http://d3w9501.americas.hpqcorp.net/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc"
            BindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleWCF"
            Contract="TestSimpleWCF.svc.ISimpleWCF"
            >
        </EndPoint>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleWCF" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>    
    </EndPoints>
</ServiceReference>
```

Comment: If you post XML, please make sure to highlight all the lines containing XML, and then click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to format your XML in a way that it will show up - nicely formatted and syntax highlighted - in your post!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set MaxReceivedMessageSize in app.config to higher value.

Like here :
[alt text http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/niemguy/7378/o_02%20-%20Properties%20BasicHttpBinding.jpg](http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/niemguy/7378/o_02%20-%20Properties%20BasicHttpBinding.jpg)

Comment: set the service contract method to return top 992 rows it works

if i set it to return 993 rows it has an error.
wcf 3.0 compiled using VS.Net 2005

can not debug the wcf but have a test console app that opens / calls the method.

Here is the error message:
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://d3w9501.americas.hpqcorp.net/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.